# ESP8266 not working after baud rate change

Tags: esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266, baud-rate

Hello guys I have my ESP8266 connected to my Arduino. Then I typed in AT in the serial monitor. It confirmed this command with OK. After that I typed in  AT+UART=9600, 8, 1, 0, 0 which gave me the response ERROR. Then I googled what I could do, which told me that I should try change the baud rate permanently with the command AT+IPR=9600. I  did this but I got no response. After that I wondered if everything was ok so I typed in AT. No response. Now I'm a little bit sad because everything started to be great but I don't know how I can fix the whole problem. I also tried to upgrade its firmware with XTCOM Utility but it says it can't connect.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial ESPserial(2, 3); // RX | TX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // communication with the host computer
  
  //while (!Serial) { ; }
  
  // Start the software serial for communication with the ESP8266
  
  ESPserial.begin(115200);
  
  Serial.println("");
  
  Serial.println("Remember to to set Both NL & CR in the serial monitor.");
  
  Serial.println("Ready");
  
  Serial.println("");

}

void loop() {
  // listen for communication from the ESP8266 and then write it to the serial monitor
  
  if ( ESPserial.available() ) { Serial.write( ESPserial.read() ); }
  
  // listen for user input and send it to the ESP8266
  
  if ( Serial.available() ) { ESPserial.write( Serial.read() ); }
}
```

This is my code. I tried it with both 9600 and 115200 but if I use 115200 the serial monitor just shows some garbage signs. It's kind of frustrating because I can't even interact with the serial monitor as my typed commands don't show up anymore. Do you have any idea how I could fix this problem?

EDIT:

I read that the command AT+IPR=9600 breaks the module and it can just be fixed by reflashing it. Sadly this doesn't work because it somehow can`t connect.

Comment: why do you still have `ESPserial.begin(115200);`? this will echo the commands: `if ( Serial.available() ) { char a = Serial.read(); Serial.write(a); ESPserial.write(a); }`

Comment: What else should i use?

Comment: after switching the firmware to 9600 baud you should use `ESPserial.begin(9600);`

Comment: yes i also used that but it doesnt do anything

Comment: https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?t=1997

Comment: yeah i tried that before but somehow i can't flash it because it doesn't connect